# I am getting error in my dataSnapshot in addValueEventListener

Tags: java

I have this event listener in my code. i want to get the values in firebase. but my variable'ds' is not being recognized when getting it in my .`getValue()` method.`

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                showData(dataSnapshot);
            }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren());

    UserInformation uInfo = new UserInformation();

    uInfo.setAddress(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getAddress());

    uInfo.setDate(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getDate());

    uInfo.setName(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getName());

    uInfo.setPhone(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getPhone());

    uInfo.setQuantity(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getQuantity());

    Log.d(TAG, "showData: address" + uInfo.getAddress());

    Log.d(TAG, "showData: date" + uInfo.getDate());

    Log.d(TAG, "showData: name" + uInfo.getName());

    Log.d(TAG, "showData: phone" + uInfo.getPhone());

    Log.d(TAG, "showData: quantity" + uInfo.getQuantity());
```

` i am getting the error "cannot found the symbol ds"

Comment: thanks...i saw the mistake of not opening my for loop statement. but my view is showing empty view. is not getting my values from database(firebase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're cancelling your for loop instantly:

```
for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren());
```

you need to provide a code block for your for loop, e.g.:

```
for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    // do stuff with ds here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ds` is defined in the scope of the `for` loop which has en empty body. You're trying to access it outside the loop.

```
for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

    UserInformation uInfo = new UserInformation();
    // ds is available here
    uInfo.setName(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getName()); 
    ...
}
```